# Can Protective Field passive ability protect multiple cards?

Tags: siege-storm

Let's say that my opponent plays an action that affects multiple cards on my track. Can Protective Field stop that action? Is this ability limited to stopping cards that only target **a single** card?

[image: Protective Field card]

Comment: Since the Kickstarter hasn't even happened yet, do we have a source for official rules answers?

Comment: @bwarner before Kickstarter there was a small release of two armies - Styxia and Seraphia, packed in one box. You can find more information  (all cards and rules) on [official page](http://www.siegestorm.com). BTW Kickstarter is launching today, 3 pm GMT